# Google Chat (Spaces) Add Member as Manager

Tags: google-api, google-chat, google-api-javascript-client

I am attempting to add different users to a Google Space and set their roles as Members or Managers.  When I try to set the role to **ROLE_MANAGER**, it always defaults to **ROLE_MEMBER**.  In reading the [reference](https://developers.google.com/chat/api/reference/rest/v1/spaces.members#Membership) and seeing that "role" is output only, this appears impossible currently.

However, when I view the documentation from [Google APIs Node.js Client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis) when I hover over the function , it does state that I can specify the role as part of RequestBody:

```
 // Request body metadata
    requestBody: {
      // request body parameters
      // {
      //   "createTime": "my_createTime",
      //   "member": {},
      //   "name": "my_name",
      //   "role": "my_role",
      //   "state": "my_state"
      // }
    },
```

An example of this is:

```
const res = await chat.spaces.members.create({
        parent: 'spaces/XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        requestBody: {
            member: {
                name: member,
                type: 'HUMAN',
            },
            role: 'ROLE_MANAGER',
        },
    });
    console.log(res);
```

Does anyone know if there is another way to set the role to "ROLE_MANAGER" for a user being added to a Space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to assign the role 'ROLE_MANAGER' when adding a user to the chat space at yet.

As stated in the document you mentioned:

> Output only. User's role within a Chat space, which determines their permitted actions in the space.

This revision clarifies the prohibition on assigning the 'ROLE_MANAGER' role.

However, you have the option to request this feature from [google chat API support](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:350158&s=created_time:desc).